# Is there any alternative to eclipse LogCat?

Tags: eclipse, logcat

Maybe I'm too spoiled with Visual Studio debugger but eclipse' LogCat seems really ugly tool to me.

1. Exceptions not descriptive so much
2. Sometimes hard to locate exceptions
3. Ugly interface which wasting my time

If I'm wrong, please tell me some good tutorial of LogCat which prooves that it could speed up my work, if not - is there any alternative to LogCat (maybe plugin)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intellij IDEA turned out a good alternative, plus logback. Reading logs now a bit easier for me.